# Incompatible lengths error while trying to load data in HDB

Tags: kdb

I have created a sample quote keyed table in KDB , keyed on fields ( time and sym). I am trying to save it in HDB using the function **.Q.dpft[`:\mydir;.z.d;`sym;`quotetbl]**  which gives me a length error. `(incompatible lengths ( different lengths of operands for synchronised operation or table columns lengths are not same).

I tried to check the number of element in each column in table by `count each flip 0!quotetbl` by first unkeying table then making a dictionary out of it and then taking the count for each key in dictionary. They are all same.

I tried to run `meta quotetbl` and it gives me attributes like below:-

```
c         t  f  a
------------------
time      p     s
sym       s
bid       f
ask       f
loc       s
bidsize   j
asksize   j
```

In the error trap mode when I try and run `.Q.bt` and `.Q.trp` command I get the below

```
 q)) .Q.bt
 k) {1'pl'(2*4<|/#:'v)_v:1_btx L1`;}

 q)) .Q.trp
 k) {-105!(x;,y;z)}
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a keyed table, but `.Q.dpft` only operates on simple tables, per https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#dpft-save-table

Comment: @JamesLittle There were 2 issues to it, first I was trying to save a keyed table as you said. But the error was because I had this saved for a previous day and schema for the recent save and earlier save were not same , leading to length error.